# How can I use css or jquery to change a button image and animate it on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On this site: https://usyouthbilliards.com/home/ there is a "Contact Us" button that, when clicked, causes a contact form to slide in. I have been trying to get the actual "Contact Us" button to change to an "X" that rotates as the panel comes out, exactly like it does on this example site: https://www.future500idcamp.com/ but I can't seem to get that to work. Can someone please help me figure this out? Thank you

I tried to just use simple css, and jquery to target the button, but I obviously am doing it incorrectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.ncf-tab-icon').rotate({maxAngle:25,minAngle:-55,
bind: [
{"mouseover":function(){$(this).rotateAnimation(85); } },
{"mouseout":function(){$(this).rotateAnimation(-35); } }]});
});
</script>
```

This code did nothing. Not sure if I am targeting the element incorrectly, or if the script is not correct or if I am completely off the mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a pen with almost exactly what you need. Just tweak it a bit to your liking.
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ionasskopelitis/pen/VgaeWy)

```js
$('a').click(function (){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
a {
  right: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #CD1349;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: transform .3s;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
a span:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
a.active {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
a.active span:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}
a.active span:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  <span>Contact Us</span>
  <span>
    x
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: That looks promising. when I change a to target the .ncf-tab-icon element, all that happens is the button image is flipped upside down. I'm obviously doing this incorrectly

Comment: try changing the transform: rotate(90deg); to what fits your needs. And maybe mark my comment as the answer?

Comment: There is no rotation animation at all. The button is just upside down, permanently

Comment: That is weird. are you sure you are using the correct html markup?

Comment: This slider is created by a wordpress plugin, so if I edit the plugin code/html it will break on updates. I was hoping for a solution that would be possible without doing that.

Comment: Sorry i didn't know. can you edit the  question wiht the html markup you are using? I can update the codepen then.

Comment: <div class="nks_cc_trigger_tabs ncf_tab ncf_label_visible nks_metro" style="display: block;"><span class="fa-stack ncf-tab-icon fa-lg fa-3x"> <i class="fa ncf-icon-square fa-stack-2x "></i> <i class="fa ncf-icon-mail-alt fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i> </span></div>

Comment: I dont get it. Are you any good with css? because you can just change the span:nth-child(1) and span:nth-child(2) to the two elements you need to switch between.

Comment: Please take a look ath this pen: https://codepen.io/ionasskopelitis/pen/VgaeWy @Carl

Comment: Apparently not too good, lol. I tried that and I can;t seem to get it all to come together. This may be out of my scope of abilities

Comment: I have the pen open

Comment: @Carl not trying to be rude here but this is stackexchange not getafreedeveloper. You have an answer to your question it is on you to implement it correctly.